# Error con Insert MSSQL, PetaPoco y C# (WPF)

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, visual-studio-2017, orm

Buen día, estoy desarrollando una aplicación de escritorio utilizando WPF, en *visual Studio 2017*; y estoy utilizando la libreria de *PetaPoco* para el CRUD con SQL.

Quisiera saber si pudisen asesorarme en este caso, ya que no encuentro mucha información en la pagina de soporte de PetaPoco, y no logro comprender exactamente cual es la razón del error.
Gracias de Antemano.

El error es el siguiente, y aparece cuando trato de insertar un nuevo registro con el método Insert de PetaPoco.

**"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."**
[image: Exception mostrada por el error al tratar de Insertar]

Aquí el código:

```
Database db = new Database("Conexion");

 [TableName("PEDIMENTOIMP")]
    [PrimaryKey("idPedimento")]
    public class Prueba
    {
        [Column]
        public int NoPedimento { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public int YearFact { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public int ipTipo { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public int idClavePed { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public DateTime FechaInicial { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public DateTime FechaFinal { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public double TipoCambio { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public string NoAgente { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public string ClaveAduana { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public string Semana { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public string AcuseRecibo { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public string AcuseReciboFact { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public int idPedimento { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public int Consolidado { get; set; }
    }

public void InserInto()
    {
        var pedimento = new Prueba
        {
            NoPedimento = 1253,
            YearFact = 2018,
            ipTipo = 1,
            idClavePed = 1,
            FechaInicial = DateTime.Now,
            FechaFinal = DateTime.Now,
            Fecha = DateTime.Now,
            TipoCambio = 1,
            ClaveAduana = "1",
            NoAgente = "1",
            Semana = "1",
            AcuseRecibo = "1",
            AcuseReciboFact = "1",
            Consolidado =1
        };

db.Insert("PEDIMENTOIMP", "idPedimento",false,  pedimento)
```

Concretamente me da error en en el segmento de código:

```
object id = _provider.ExecuteInsert(this, cmd, primaryKeyName);
                    // Assign the ID back to the primary key property
                    if (primaryKeyName != null && !poco.GetType().Name.Contains("AnonymousType"))
                    {
                        PocoColumn pc;
                        if (pd.Columns.TryGetValue(primaryKeyName, out pc))
                        {
                            pc.SetValue(poco, pc.ChangeType(id));
                        }
                    }
```

del archivo de PetaPoco.cs

Comment: Me parece que estás asignando un valor a 'pc' a través de la clásula 'out' cuando aún no lo has instanceado, solo lo declaraste pero hasta ese momento es null.

PocoColumn pc = new PocoColumn();

Solo es una primera impresión pero sería bueno poner un punto de interrupción y ver que linea es la que provoca el error.

Comment: @Leodev Los parámetros tipo out no requieren instanciarse antes de pasarlos al método (ref si).  Angel Lara, ¿has depurado tu código y verificado el valor de las variables? te recomiendo conocer mas las herramientas que te da Visual Studio.